# Google Sheets Script > When a row is added to to one of the 3 sheets, copy new row to a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I'm quite new to Google Sheets Script. I'm trying to automatically consolidate data from 3 different sheets that a have the same data structure to a different sheet (in same spreadsheet or in different spreadsheet).

Here is a [Google Sheet Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CnYQUSbrpwbJKlqo0lLAy-mYmW_WS7g_TtAPhPr5sKo/edit?usp=sharing).

Many thanks. S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [`=QUERY()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function for this. As an example:

```
=QUERY({'SHEET 1'!A1:D; 'SHEET 2'!A2:D;'SHEET 3'!A2:D}; "SELECT * WHERE Col1 != ''"; 1)
```

[image: example result]

Comment: Thanks! This is a perfect approach / solution. Best. S.